# PHPUnit & Selenium code coverage - coverage metrics stop halfway through test

Tags: selenium, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm just getting started with PHPUnit and Selenium, yet one problem has been bothering me: I can't seem to get correct coverage figures.

My app takes a user through a multi-step process that involves multiple pages, each of which is handled in PHP by a display function (to output HTML) and a processing function (to handle the results of POST operations). My baseline test runs through the entire process, and completes correctly having visited each of about seven pages. I've both verified this visually and through assertions in the testcase itself.

This issue is that the coverage report indicates that only the first couple of functions are executed and that the others are never visited (despite my visual and testcase checks). I thought the problem was a PHP Notice that occurred during the first function and that might stop XDebug/PHPUnit from collecting stats, but I fixed this and the problem remains.

Is there anything that can stop collection of coverage statistics mid-way through a test? All the functions in question are in the same file and are called from a (different) central PHP script which chooses which function to call based on an incrementing session variable.

Comment: I gave up on trying to get code coverage results from Selenium. I found it to be very buggy. The other problem is my unit tests would give one set of coverage data, and the integration tests would give another. I stick to using PHPUnit for unit tests - and measure code coverage there. IMHO - Unit tests are more robust, easier to maintain, and provide more feedback about code path. Integration tests are a final "sanity check" to make sure everything works as expected. If you find you're able to get usable coverage results from Selenium / PHPUnit - Please share!